# Efficient Text Processing Java

Tags: java, performance

I have created an application to process log files but am having some bottle neck when the amount of files = ~20

The issue comes from a particular method which takes on average a second or so to complete roughly and as you can imagime this isn't practical when it needs to be done > 50 times

```
private String getIdFromLine(String line){
    String[] values = line.split("\t");
    String newLine = substringBetween(values[4], "Some String : ", "Value=");
     String[] split = newLine.split(" ");
     return split[1].substring(4, split[1].length());
}



private String substringBetween(String str, String open, String close) {
      if (str == null || open == null || close == null) {
          return null;
      }
      int start = str.indexOf(open);
      if (start != -1) {
          int end = str.indexOf(close, start + open.length());
          if (end != -1) {
              return str.substring(start + open.length(), end);
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
```

A line comes from the reading of a file which is very efficient so I don't feel a need to post that code unless someone asks.

Is there anyway to improve perofmrance of this at all?

Thanks for your time

Comment: It would be useful perhaps if you also provide an example of a line that is being parsed here... would make the code easier to read.

Comment: i would love to but it is sensitive work data - not sure i could sensibly change it

Comment: well you can create a dummy one, something like `xxx: aaa->bbb, ccc dd cc ee`. I think a more efficient algo would depend a lot on what kind of data you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things are likely problematic:

1. Whether or not you realized, you *are* using regular expressions.  The argument to `String.split()` is a treated as a regex.  Using `String.indexOf()` will almost certainly be a faster way to find the particular portion of the String that you want.  As HRgiger points out, Guava's splitter is a good choice because it does just that.
2. You're allocating a bunch of stuff you don't need.  Depending on how long your lines are, you could be creating a ton of extra `String`s and `String[]`s that you don't need (and the garbage collecting them).  Another reason to avoid `String.split()`.
3. I also recommend using `String.startsWith()` and `String.endsWith()` rather that all of this stuff that you're doing with the `indexOf()` if only for the fact that it'd be easier to read.

Comment: I'm agree with your advices. +1

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use regular expressions.

Comment: Why do you think that? I would give them a chance. Testing and comparing is the best way to get best result anyway.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main problems in this code is the "`split`" method.
For example this one:

```
    private String getIdFromLine3(String line) {
        int t_index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            t_index = line.indexOf("\t", t_index+1);
            if (t_index == -1) return null;
        }
        //String[] values = line.split("\t");
        String newLine = substringBetween(line.substring(t_index + 1), "Some String : ", "Value=");
//        String[] split = newLine.split(" ");
        int p_index = newLine.indexOf(" ");
        if (p_index == -1) return null;
        int p_index2 = newLine.indexOf(" ", p_index+1);
        if (p_index2 == -1) return null;
        String split = newLine.substring(p_index+1, p_index2);

//        return split[1].substring(4, split[1].length());
        return split.substring(4, split.length());
    }
```

**UPD**: It ***could*** be 3 times faster.

Comment: Why would you think that this would be 3x faster?

Comment: Given that you don't have his input data, it seems somewhat unlikely that you could have tested your implementation in any way that resembles the issue encountered by the original poster.

Comment: well, actually we haven't SkyR's input data, but we can *approximately* evaluate performance of this algorithm on some array of strings for which this code gives some sensible result.

Comment: No, you can't.  You can describe the algorithmic complexity (which, for what it's worth, is better), but you couldn't possibly make any reasonable statement about how long it might take to execute.  For example, a String with 4GB of characters before the first tab and 100B of characters after would likely run at virtually the same speed.  If this were the case, then perhaps SkyR should try iterating over the string backwards.  Who knows?  The point is that for "some array of strings" the result will be nonsense.

Comment: Ok, I'm agree. Can I say, that it "could be" ... xxx times faster?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use the [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to find the bottle neck before oprimisation.
If you need performance in your application, you will need profiling anyways.

As optimisation i would make an custom loop to replace yours `substringBetween` method and get rid of multiple `indexOf` calls

Answer (score 0):

[Google guava splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) pretty fast as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the regex anyway and post results please just for comparison:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Some String : )(.*?)(Value=)"); //remove first and last group if not needed (adjust m.group(x) to match

@Test
public void test2(){
    String str = "Long java line with Some String : and some object with Value=154345 ";
    System.out.println(substringBetween(str));      
}

private String substringBetween(String str) {       
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if(m.find(2)){
        return m.group(2);          
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

If this is faster find a regex that combines both functions